# Can I force visdiff to display more than the first 2000 bytes?

Tags: matlab, diff, binaryfiles

I have two binary files that I'm trying to compare using Matlab's built-in function [`visdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/visdiff.html), but it only displays the first 2000 bytes as a default. Is there any way to force the comparison tool to display the entire contents of both files side by side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the file `matlabroot\toolbox\shared\comparisons\private\bindiff.m`, where `matlabroot` is your MATLAB installation directory. On line 149, you'll see it sets the variable `MAXLEN` to 2000. Change this to something bigger (even `Inf` seems to work).

You may need to type `rehash toolboxcache` after making this change, in order to get MATLAB to notice.

Please note:

1. As you're making a change to the MATLAB source, this is at your own risk (it seems fine to me though). Keep a backup of the file you've edited.
2. That truncation at 2000 bytes is there for a reason - comparing the whole of larger binary files does seem to take quite a while, so be patient. Maybe try gradually increasing `MAXLEN`, rather than going straight to `Inf`.
3. I only have R2011b available to me right now, so if you're on a newer version the file path and line number I mentioned above may have changed. It was very easy to trace through the code from `visdiff` to `comparisons_private` to `bindiff` though, so unless they've changed the deeper structure of the Comparisons Tool between 11b and now, it will probably be very similar.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. Takes 15-20 seconds for a 110 kB file on my machine.

Comment: Great, glad it works for you. It seems to me that this would be a simple and useful thing for MathWorks to add as a Preference setting - if you have a MathWorks account, why not submit it as a feature request?